# Intermittant "Permission Denied" error when compiling Latex document with Knitr and openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, latex, knitr

I am using a data set that has been provided in an xlsx workbook across several worksheets. I created a function to extract the data from one of the sheets and reformat it into a usable form.

Opening the file twice in one compilation of Latex often (but not all the time) triggers the following error:

```
Error in unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Jonno/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpewoYVY/_excelXMLRead/xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml': Permission denied
```

This suggests that the temporary file is not being closed which prevents openxlsx from unzipping the xlsx file again. 
Unfortunately the file needs to be opened several times to extract the data.
Also unfortunately I haven't been able to create a reproducible example suggests that it may be something to do with the structure of the file I have received.

Is there a way to force the temporary file to be closed and deleted after each  time it is opened?

This problem only occurs when knitting, when it is run in the R enivironment this problem never occurs.

Comment: "I created a function to extract the data from one of the sheets and reformat it into a usable form." --> Details on how this function looks like could be helpful.